# Have Excel Chart only show current month and YTD

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m currently working on creating a dynamic chart which is updated monthly in accordance with the information imported into the excel file.

The table is updated with the information, where the chart is supposed to only show the current month based on a specific cell, shown in the attached excel file.

Example text

```
Period 01JAN18 0001 to 31JAN18 2259
```

What the chart needs to do is match the text with a month, so if the text says “JAN” it’s supposed to grab the data for January, if it says “FEB” it’s supposed to grab the data for February.

Currently the chart shows the data for every single month, where I then have to filter out the current month and Year To Date.

[Link to excel file](https://ufile.io/io40h)

[image: Image of excel file]

I hope this explains it properly :)

I am also open to coding it in VBA if necessary.

Comment: While it's a good thing that you included a picture, there's no data on it and you haven't asked an actual question. I'd love to help you but I don't know what should I help you with.

Comment: Hi, the data is sadly something I can't really share. I'm not sure why the data would be neccesary for the chart, it's a matter of changing the chart selection to each month based on the cell "A2".

Comment: It's good to come up with made up example data if that's the case. I think pivot tables/charts might be the most common solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi, I attached an image with some data on it. @M.Douda

Comment: Your question is extrememly unclear, read though [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Type out your sample data in text so it can be copied and pasted into excel, post example images of the chart you have, the chart you want and a much clearer explanation of what is currently missing.

Comment: Hi @Dan Working on a rework of it all now, my apologies for being unclear. Probably worked on this issue for too long

Comment: Updated it now, hope it can be understood now, I don't think it's off-topic since I am open to either a formula or VBA. Whichever is easiest.

Comment: I understand that @RichardTompsett - I have added an image link of the data.

Comment: August might be a bad example since it was JAN, my apologies. It's supposed to show January when "JAN" is shown in the period. The YTD value automatically updates with sum, so no need to worry, that one just has to be always shown while the month has to be dynamic.

Comment: Okay then I see where this is going, one quick question before I proceed, is the date range ever going to include more than one month and will you want all months in the range included or just the start or end of the period? *example:*`Period 01JAN18 0001 to 30APR18 2259`... If it's just one month I would recommend another table (or column just before YTD) and a simple `HLOOKUP()` / `INDEX()` to return the correct month by either `SEARCH()` `MATCH()` with wildcards or parse a date value out of it and equate against the `MONTH()`

Comment: To answer your question: It will never include more than one month, it's only supposed to be the start of the period. Since it will never go over 1 month when we export from our software.

Comment: @pnuts The reasoning behind this is actually that the whole sheet itself is automated, it  pull data from a server and update the chart monthly, but I really can't just get it to only track a month at a time..

Comment: I did program some VBA already so it wouldn't hurt to actually do that, I have however never modified a chart using VBA before, so it would be a completely new area for me sadly.
I hope to be able to do it with formulas though, just for optimization sake I try to avoid VBA where Excel can be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered on Superuser since it was requested that I posted there instead.
https://superuser.com/questions/1321124/have-excel-chart-only-show-current-month-and-ytd/1321252#1321252